# How to share the webdriver instance between TestThreadContainer and FeatureContainer in a specflow project?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, xunit, specflow

In the specflow hook file, I have to share the webdriver instance across multiple containers like TestThreadContainer, FeatureContainer and ScenarioContainer.

In the below code, I'm not able to share webDriverManager instance between BeforeTestRun (TestThreadContainer) and BeforeFeature (FeatureContainer). Driver details are not being available for BeforeFeature, so I'm getting an exception while executing the BeforeFeature block. Basically, I want to share data between two different containers, is that possible?

```
using Automation.authentication.Helper;
using Automation.core;
using Automation.core.Configuration;
using Automation.core.Helper;
using Automation.core.Pages;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
using Xunit.Abstractions;

namespace ecui_e2e.Hooks
{
  [Binding]
  public sealed class Hooks
  {   

    [BeforeTestRun]
    public static void BeforeTestRun(WebDriverManager webDriverManager)
    {
        webDriverManager.StartWebDriver();
    }

    [BeforeFeature]
    public static void BeforeFeatureRun(WebDriverManager webDriverManager)
    {
      if (!webDriverManager.IsWebDriverLoggedin(_testUserAccount))
      {
        var login = ConfigurationHelper.EnvironmentConfiguration.Login
        new LoginHelper(webDriverManager).LoginToSite(
        login.UserName,
        login.Password);
        webDriverManager.SetDriverLoggedIn(_testUserAccount);
      }
    }

    [AfterTestRun]
    public static void AfterTestRun(WebDriverManager webDriverManager)
    {
      webDriverManager.ReleaseWebDrivers();
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the WebDriverManager Class

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Automation.core
{
  public class WebDriverManager
  {
    public string FeatureKey { get; set; }

    public string ActiveDriverKey;
    public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, bool> WebDriverLoginStatus { get; private set; } = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, bool>();

    public static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, IWebDriver> WebDrivers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, IWebDriver>();
    public IWebDriver WebDriver { get; private set; }
    public WebDriverManager()
    {

    }
    public void SetDriverLoggedIn(string driverKey)
    {
      var featureDriverKey = driverKey;
      if (WebDriverLoginStatus.ContainsKey(featureDriverKey))
      {
        WebDriverLoginStatus[featureDriverKey] = true;
      }
      else
      {
        throw new Exception($"Missing driver for key { driverKey }");
      }
    }
    public void SwitchWebDriver(string driverKey)
    {
      this.StartWebDriver(driverKey);
    }
    public void StartWebDriver(string driverKey)
    {
      var featureDriverKey = driverKey;
      var env = ConfigurationHelper.EnvironmentConfiguration;
      if (!WebDrivers.ContainsKey(featureDriverKey))
      {
        var webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
        webDriver.Manage().Window.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1920, 1080);
        webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(env.BaseUrl);
        WebDrivers.TryAdd(featureDriverKey, webDriver);
      }
      ActiveDriverKey = driverKey;
      if (!WebDriverLoginStatus.ContainsKey(featureDriverKey))
      {
        WebDriverLoginStatus.TryAdd(featureDriverKey, false);
      }

      WebDriver = WebDrivers.GetValueOrDefault(featureDriverKey);
    }
    public bool IsWebDriverLoggedin(string driverKey)
    {
      var isLoggedin = WebDriverLoginStatus.GetValueOrDefault(driverKey);
      return isLoggedin;
    }
    public void ReleaseWebDrivers()
    {
      WebDrivers.Keys.ToList().ForEach(key =>
      {
          IWebDriver webDriver;
          WebDrivers.Remove(key, out webDriver);
          webDriver.Quit();
          webDriver.Dispose();
      });

      WebDriverLoginStatus.Keys.ToList().ForEach(key =>
      {
          bool isLoggedIn;
          WebDriverLoginStatus.Remove(key, out isLoggedIn);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is "containers" a term used in xUnit? The term "container" is very general. I am also not aware of a "FeatureContainer" class in SpecFlow.

Comment: I don't recognize the attributes in your code here, In XUnit you can share objects across tests using a "connection fixture". See the documentation at https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context

Comment: @ChristopherHamkins: the attributes in the code come from SpecFlow, which is a behavior-driven development framework that integrates with multiple unit test frameworks, including xUnit.

Comment: I don't think we can see enough code. Can you [edit] your question to include the WebDriverManager class? Have a look at https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/Hooks.html for more information on how to use hooks. I suspect you cannot pass a WebDriverManager object to the BeforeFeature hook, but you can pass a FeatureContext object.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I have edited my question to include the WebDriverManager class

Comment: Can you include more information about what "share" means in this context? Two different threads cannot use the same web driver instance at the same time.

Comment: Have a look at my answer on [How do I run every example in a scenario outline in a single browser session?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73561171/3092298). I'm not sure if this answers your question, though. It does feel similar.