# How do I run every example in a scenario outline in a single browser session?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, specflow

## The short version

I have a SpecFlow scenario outline which uses Selenium to test a web page. The scenario outline has many rows of `Examples` test data and for performance reasons I would like to open one browser window and run every test in that window, rather than opening a new browser window for every row in the test data.

## My minimal reproducible example

### Application being tested

This is a basic web page which allows the user to input two numbers, multiplies them and displays the result.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <!-- Multiply this number... -->
    <input type="text" id="operand1" />
    *
    <!-- ...by this number... -->
    <input type="text" id="operand2" />
    =
    <!-- ...and the result should be displayed here... -->
    <span id="product"></span>
    <div>
        <!-- ...when I click this button -->
        <input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate()" />
    </div>

    <!-- import jQuery so that I can be confident about browser compatibility -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"
            integrity="sha512-aVKKRRi/Q/YV+4mjoKBsE4x3H+BkegoM/em46NNlCqNTmUYADjBbeNefNxYV7giUp0VxICtqdrbqU7iVaeZNXA=="
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            referrerpolicy="no-referrer">
    </script>

    <!-- the script which does the multiplication -->
    <script>
        function calculate() {
            var operand1 = $('#operand1').val();
            var operand2 = $('#operand2').val();
            var product = operand1 * operand2;
            $('#product').text(product);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Feature file

```
Feature: Multiplication

As someone who's no good at mental arithmetic
I want something to multiply one number by another number
So that I can know the answer without working it out myself

Background:
    Given I am on the multiplication page

Scenario Outline: Multiply two numbers
    Given the first number is <operand1>
    And the second number is <operand2>
    When I click the calculate button
    Then the result should be <product>
    Examples:
    | operand1 | operand2 | product |
    | 1        | 2        | 2       |
    | 2        | 2        | 4       |
    | 3        | 2        | 6       |
    | 4        | 2        | 8       |
    # Rather than make you scroll through hundreds of lines of test data,
    # I'd like you to imagine that there are hundreds of lines of test
    # data here. What the data is doesn't really matter.
```

### Step definitions

```
    using OpenQA.Selenium;

    [Binding]
    public sealed class MultiplicationSteps : Steps
    {
        private readonly IWebDriver driver;

        public MultiplicationSteps(ScenarioContext context)
        {
            this.driver = (IWebDriver)context["driver"];
        }

        [Given(@"I am on the multiplication page")]
        public void GivenIAmOnTheMultiplicationPage()
        {
            this.driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"file:///C:/path/to/multiplier.html");
        }

        [Given("the first number is (.*)")]
        public void GivenTheFirstNumberIs(int number)
        {
            var operand1Box = this.driver.FindElement(By.Id("operand1"));
            operand1Box.Clear();
            operand1Box.SendKeys(number.ToString());
        }

        [Given("the second number is (.*)")]
        public void GivenTheSecondNumberIs(int number)
        {
            var operand2Box = this.driver.FindElement(By.Id("operand2"));
            operand2Box.Clear();
            operand2Box.SendKeys(number.ToString());
        }

        [When("I click the calculate button")]
        public void WhenIClickTheCalculateButton()
        {
            var calculateButton = this.driver.FindElement(By.Id("calculate"));
            calculateButton.Click();
        }

        [Then("the result should be (.*)")]
        public void ThenTheResultShouldBe(int expectedProduct)
        {
            var productDiv = this.driver.FindElement(By.Id("product"));
            var product = productDiv.Text;
            Assert.Equal(expectedProduct.ToString(), product);
        }
    }
```

### Hooks

```
    using OpenQA.Selenium;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

    [Binding]
    public class Hooks : Steps
    {
        [BeforeScenario]
        public void BeforeScenario()
        {
            if (!this.ScenarioContext.ContainsKey("driver"))
            {
                this.ScenarioContext["driver"] = new ChromeDriver();
            }
        }

        [AfterScenario]
        public void AfterScenario()
        {
            var driver = this.ScenarioContext["driver"] as IWebDriver;
            if (driver != null)
            {
                driver.Quit();
                driver.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

### What's wrong?

Functionally this is fine, the tests all pass, but the performance sucks because it's opening a new browser window for every row in the `Examples` test data, because `[BeforeScenario]` runs once per row in the `Examples` rather than once for the whole `Scenario Outline`. Opening and closing all those browser windows adds an awful lot to the total execution time.

## What I've tried

### BeforeFeature / AfterFeature

It feels like I need a `[BeforeScenarioOutline]`, but that's not a thing. The next level up is `[BeforeFeature]`, so I tried storing the `IWebDriver` in the `FeatureContext` instead of the `ScenarioContext` like this:

```
        [BeforeFeature]
        public void BeforeFeature()
        {
            this.FeatureContext["driver"] = new ChromeDriver();
        }

        [AfterFeature]
        public void AfterFeature()
        {
            var driver = this.FeatureContext["driver"] as IWebDriver;
            if (driver != null)
            {
                driver.Quit();
                driver.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

But this results in a build warning and runtime error

> The binding methods for before/after feature and before/after test run events must be static!

And of course if I make those methods `static` then they can't access the instance property `this.FeatureContext`. The same is true of `BeforeTestRun` and `AfterTestRun`.

### Static class to hold the IWebDriver

This class will instantiate the IWebDriver at some point before I want to use it:

```
    public static class TheDriver
    {
        private static readonly IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        public static IWebDriver Driver => driver;
    }
```

And I changed the step definitions constructor to this:

```
        public MultiplicationSteps()
        {
            this.driver = TheDriver.Driver;
        }
```

And now I can make use of `[AfterTestRun]` to close the browser at the end of the test run.

```
        [AfterTestRun]
        public static void AfterTestRun()
        {
            if (TheDriver.Driver != null)
            {
                TheDriver.Driver.Quit();
                TheDriver.Driver.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

This works as long as I only have one feature file. But it's not thread safe - as soon as I try running two features in parallel the tests fail because both features are trying to work with the same browser window.

## Summary

I feel like I'm missing something important about how to use `BeforeFeature`, `AfterFeature` and `FeatureContext` correctly. Unfortunately the [SpecFlow hooks documentation](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/Hooks.html) doesn't say a great deal about how to go about this.

## My tech stack

- .net 6.0
- Selenium.WebDriver 4.4.0
- SpecFlow 3.9.40
- xunit 2.4.1

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this without also controlling the test runner threads. You basically need one web driver per thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Using Hooks with Parameter Injection](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/Hooks.html#using-hooks-with-parameter-injection) in the SpecFlow documentation describes how to access the FeatureContext from a `[BeforeFeature]` hook. It is deceptively simply, actually. Declare a FeatureContext object as a parameter to your BeforeFeature hook:

```
[BeforeFeature]
public static void CreateWebDriver(FeatureContext feature)
{ //                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    feature["driver"] = new ChromeDriver();
}

[AfterFeature]
public static void DestroyWebDriver(FeatureContext feature)
{ //                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    var driver = (IWebDriver)feature["driver"];

    driver.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Nice simple answer and it works perfectly. I just needed to understand the right dependency and where to inject it. Thank you, answer accepted and upvoted :-)

Comment: @sbridewell: sometimes it is not clear from the SpecFlow documentation what objects can be passed to hooks. Glad it helped.